# body or window outside of element remove same element with click in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

want to delete  when the user clicks anywhere on the page except the .

In addition, the checked to remain in  after remove  or when the user clicks No, remove checked in  and

Please help me to do this work. If you have a suggestion for solving this problem, thank you for letting me know. Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
const confirm = document.getElementById('confirm');
confirm.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const yes = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  const yesItems = document.getElementById('yes-items');
  if (yes.checked == true) {
    yesItems.style.display = "block";
  }
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.yes.checked == true) {
      yesItems.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
items {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

span.yes-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid var(--c1);
  color: var(--txt);
  background-color: #e6eef7;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 94%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}

span.yes-items input {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class="items">
  <span class="label">example</span>
  <span class="label-items">
    <label class="label-item" for="okey" id="confirm">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Yes" id="okey">
      Yes
    </label>
    <label class="label-item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="No" id="No">
      No
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="yes-items" id="yes-items"><span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      1
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      2
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      3
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      4
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      other
      <textarea class="explain" placeholder="Define Other" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>                       
    </label>
  </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: you can get clicked element using `event.target`

Comment: Could you check the first two sentences as they are displayed in  your question as they don't quite make sense. What is the stuff you don't want to delete and what comes after the and at the end of the second sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Its Very simple,

- Just Create And Put All Items into `div#body`
- And You Have to use the event `window.onclick`
- Then create `if` statement and check `event.target.id == "body"` ( To Check The Clicked Element is the `div#body` ( Not Its Children ) )
- `if (event.target.id == "body"){ /* Hiding Code */ }`

*Example*

```js
var w = window;
var a = document.getElementById("example");
var c = document.getElementById("okay");
var e = document.getElementById("yes-items");
a.addEventListener("click", check);
w.addEventListener("click", clickedBody);

function clickedBody(event){
  if(event.target.id == "body"){
    hideExplainIfOpened();
  }
}
function check(){
  if(c.checked){ showExplain();}
  else{ hideExplain(); }
}
function hideExplainIfOpened(){ 
  if(!e.classList.contains("d-none")){ 
    hideExplain();
  }
}

function showExplain(){ e.classList.remove("d-none"); }
function hideExplain(){ e.classList.add("d-none"); }
```

```css
#body {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  overflow:auto;
  
}
items {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

span.yes-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid var(--c1);
  color: var(--txt);
  background-color: #e6eef7;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 94%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.d-none{ display:none; }

span.yes-items input {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="body"> 
<p class="items">
  <span class="label">example</span>
  <span class="label-items" id="example">
    <label class="label-item"  for="okey" id="confirm">
      <input type="radio" class="input"  name="example" value="1" id="okay">
      Yes
    </label>
    <label class="label-item">
      <input type="radio" class="input" name="example" value="0" id="No">
      No
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="yes-items d-none" id="yes-items"><span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      1
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      2
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      3
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      4
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      other
      <textarea class="explain" placeholder="Define Other" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>                       
    </label>
  </span>
  </span>
</p>
</div>
```