# remove element (span) with click on out of same element body or window in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to click on confirm includes:(input && label), yesItems displayed.
And then click on any part of the page(body or window) except yesItems, yesItems to delete.
in fact, I want to delete (yes-items) when the user clicks anywhere on the page except the (yes-items).
But when clicking on children of yes-items include(NodeList(16):pan, label, input),yes-items should not be deleted.
Are my codes correct?
Please help me to do this work. If you have a suggestion for solving this problem, thank you for letting me know. Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
const confirm = document.getElementById('confirm');
confirm.addEventListener('click',function(){
  const healthProblem = document.querySelector('#health-problem');
  const yesItems = document.getElementById('yes-items');
  if(healthProblem.checked == true){
    yesItems.classList.add('open');
  }else{
    yesItems.classList.remove('open');
  }   
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(!(e.target == yesItems.querySelectorAll("*"))){
   yesItems.classList.remove('open');
  }
  })
})
```

```css
items {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

span.yes-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid var(--c1);
  color: var(--txt);
  background-color: #e6eef7;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 94%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}

span.yes-items input {
  width: auto;
}

span.yes-items.open{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="items">
   <span class="label">example</span>
   <span class="label-items">
     <label class="label-item" for="health-problem" id="confirm">
        <input type="radio" id="health-problem" name="problem">
        Yes
     </label>
     <label class="label-item" for="no-problem">
        <input type="radio" id="no-problem" name="problem">
        No
      </label>
   </span>
   <span class="yes-items" id="yes-items">
     <span>                                            
       <label for="Diabetic">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
         a
       </label>
     </span>
     <span>                                            
       <label for="Diabetic">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
         b
       </label>
     </span>
     <span>                                            
       <label for="Diabetic">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
         c
       </label>
     </span>
     <span>                                            
       <label for="Diabetic">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
         d
       </label>
     </span>
     <span>                                            
       <label for="Diabetic">
         <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
         e
         <textarea class="explain" placeholder="Define Other" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea> 
       </label>
     </span>
</span>                                    
</p>
```

Comment: Why r u asking the same question ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869926/body-or-window-outside-of-element-remove-same-element-with-click-in-javascript/

Comment: hello @ N_R01   Because I did not get the answer I needed

Comment: Didn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869926/body-or-window-outside-of-element-remove-same-element-with-click-in-javascript/68870954#68870954) post answer your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [body or window outside of element remove same element with click in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869926/body-or-window-outside-of-element-remove-same-element-with-click-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869926/body-or-window-outside-of-element-remove-same-element-with-click-in-javascript/68870954#68870954) in your own question for more

*Snippet*

```js
var w = window;
var a = document.getElementById("example");
var c = document.getElementById("okay");
var e = document.getElementById("yes-items");
a.addEventListener("click", check);
w.addEventListener("click", clickedBody);

function clickedBody(event){
  if(event.target.id == "body"){
    hideExplainIfOpened();
  }
}
function check(){
  if(c.checked){ showExplain();}
  else{ hideExplain(); }
}
function hideExplainIfOpened(){ 
  if(!e.classList.contains("d-none")){ 
    hideExplain();
  }
}

function showExplain(){ e.classList.remove("d-none"); }
function hideExplain(){ e.classList.add("d-none"); }
```

```css
#body {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  overflow:auto;
  
}
items {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

span.yes-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid var(--c1);
  color: var(--txt);
  background-color: #e6eef7;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 94%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.d-none{ display:none; }

span.yes-items input {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="body"> 
<p class="items">
  <span class="label">example</span>
  <span class="label-items" id="example">
    <label class="label-item"  for="okey" id="confirm">
      <input type="radio" class="input"  name="example" value="1" id="okay">
      Yes
    </label>
    <label class="label-item">
      <input type="radio" class="input" name="example" value="0" id="No">
      No
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="yes-items d-none" id="yes-items"><span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      1
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      2
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      3
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      4
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>                                            
    <label for="Diabetic">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Diabetic" id="Diabetic">
      other
      <textarea class="explain" placeholder="Define Other" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>                       
    </label>
  </span>
  </span>
</p>
</div>
```